# Is regularization of a linear model really needed?

Tags: regression, modeling, linear-model, regularization

I'm going to do linear regression on a data set with 60k observations, each with 120 features. The way I see it, there is no why in the world that with more then 50 samples per dimension, a linear low variance model will overfit. That being said, the fact is their are regularizations methods for linear models.

So, on a healthy-sized dataset (and this is a question by itself.. I see it as the number of samples is greater then the square of the dimensionality), do I need to regularize a linear model?

Comment: When I fit models like yours with random data, I obtain plenty of spuriously "significant" variables (depending on the threshold one uses for significance). That sounds like overfitting to me--but is it what *you* mean? I'm also not sure what you mean by "low variance," but this model has an adjusted $R^2$ of $0.99$, which many consider excellent. Here is my calculation in `R`. There is only one nonzero coefficient. `p <- 120;
n <- 60000;
set.seed(17);
x <- matrix(rnorm(p*n), ncol=p);
y <- x %*% c(1,rep(0, p-1)) + rnorm(n, sd=1/10);
fit <- lm(y ~ x);
summary(fit)`

Comment: There is a good way to find out, which is to try regularization and see if it gives better out of sample prediction when the regularization parameter is tuned properly (e.g. by minimizing PRESS).  I expect there are some problems with those dimensions where an unregularized liner model is fine and others where regularization is beneficial.  As finding out is computationally inexpensive, why not just try it and see?

Comment: Trying out and seeing is something i'll definitly do. Im looking for a theoretical insight before I go ahead and try it out. In principle, how can a linear line can overfit 100 points in 2D? How will regularization change such fitting?

Comment: @whuber - Question is will regularization change the fitted model, and why?

Comment: That comment seems to change your question, so it is important that you edit the text of the question to reflect what it is you are really asking.  As far as trying out that code, it only takes as much time as you might need to paste it into a source file or window; the execution is less than a second.  The whole process will take less time than needed to write any more comments!

Comment: @idoda I don't think the number of points required to avoid over-fitting necessarily scales linearly with the number of dimensions, due to the "curse of dimensionality".  I suspect a lot depends on how the points are distributed within the 120 dimensional space.  I tend to use regularised models for most problems, if the regularisation term is unhelpful, you tend to end up with the regularisation parameter taking on a small value and the regularisation term has little effect.

Answer (score 4):

As [@Dikran Marsupial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/887/dikran-marsupial) wrote in the comments:

> There is a good way to find out, which is to try regularization and
> see if it gives better out of sample prediction when the
> regularization parameter is tuned properly (e.g. by minimizing PRESS).
> I expect there are some problems with those dimensions where an
> unregularized liner model is fine and others where regularization is
> beneficial. As finding out is computationally inexpensive, why not
> just try it and see? [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122525/is-regularization-of-a-linear-model-really-needed#comment233461_122525)

> I tend to use regularised models for most problems, if the
> regularisation term is unhelpful, you tend to end up with the
> regularisation parameter taking on a small value and the
> regularisation term has little effect. [[2]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122525/is-regularization-of-a-linear-model-really-needed#comment233628_122525)

Comment: I've copied this comment by @DikranMarsupial as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.